# Image Slider that opens images from different folders on different button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I have an image slider that opens up different images from the same folder(named the images 1.jpg,2.jpg in *folder img1*). Is it possible if I can have  buttons below the image slider that gives me a sliding images from different folders(1.jpg,2.jpg from *folder img2* ; 1.jpg,2.jpg from  *folder img3*)

```
<div id="slider">
    <img src="img/1.jpg" alt="Slide 1" />
    <img data-src="img/2.jpg" alt="Slide 2" />
    <img data-src="img/3.jpg" alt="Slide 3" />
    <img data-src="img/4.jpg" alt="Slide 4" />
</div><button>Images from new folder</button>
```

Comment: You want just switch to another folder by button click? Images names are the same in this two folders?

Comment: Yes thats exactly what I want, just on clicking the buttons present below it and the slider should fetch and display the images from folder 2. I will keep the names same.

Comment: What about the infinite change of folders which I have implemented in my answer? Is this solution OK for you, or you are searching for something else?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are using a library/code that displays the image in `data-src`.
Basically you can change the `'data-src'` (or just the images' `src`) attribute dynamically and change the path you are using.

It depends on the implementation since a lib might cache the `data-src` on initialization and then ignore changes to it..

Anyway, this is how you can do it (I'm using `src` in this example but you can change to `data-src` as well):

```js
var gallery = document.querySelector('#gallery');
var button = document.querySelector('#your-button-id');

button.addEventListener('click', () => setImagesFolder('folderName'));

function setImagesFolder(folder) {
  gallery.querySelectorAll('img').forEach(imgEl => {
    var currPath = imgEl.getAttribute('data-src');
    var basePath = currPath.slice(currPath.lastIndexOf('/'))
    console.log(folder + basePath)
    imgEl.setAttribute('src', folder + basePath)
  })
}
```

```html
<div id="gallery">
  <img data-src="folder/1.jpg">
  <img data-src="folder/2.jpg">
  <img data-src="folder/3.jpg">
  <img data-src="folder/4.jpg">
  <img data-src="folder/5.jpg">
</div>
<button id="your-button-id">Change images path</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the folder to the next infinitely via the following snippet:

```js
function logImagesPaths() {
  $("#slider").children().each(function(item) {
    console.log($(this).attr("data-src"))
  });
}

function changeFolder() {
  $("#slider").children().each(function(item) {
    var oldDataSrc = $(this).attr("data-src");
    var newDataSrc = getNewPath(oldDataSrc);
    $(this).attr("data-src", newDataSrc);
    logImagesPaths();
  });
}

function getNewPath(data) {
  var index = data.indexOf('/');
  var folder = data.substring(0, index);
  var folderNumber = folder.slice(3, folder.length);
  var newFolderNumber = parseInt(folderNumber) + 1;
  var newFolder = data.replace(folder, 'img' + newFolderNumber);
  return newFolder;
}

logImagesPaths();

$('#changeFolderBtn').on('click', changeFolder);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slider">
    <img data-src="img1/1.jpg" alt="Slide 1" />
    <img data-src="img1/2.jpg" alt="Slide 2" />
    <img data-src="img1/3.jpg" alt="Slide 3" />
    <img data-src="img1/4.jpg" alt="Slide 4" />
</div><button id="changeFolderBtn">Images from new folder</button>
```